# Не срабатывает on('click') в хроме

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я понимаю вопрос избитый. Но четкого ответа не нашел. Есть вот такой простейший код:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#client_1").on("click", function () {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id='client_1'>Click me</option>
</select>
```

В firefox и IE все работает отлично, но в хроме не срабатывает. Jquery последняя версия подключен, в консоле ни каких ошибок, файлы все подключены... Куда копасть не приложу ума.

Comment: У меня всё работает в хроме.

Comment: @Александр Черемикин  И я, и я, и я такого мнения.

Comment: @Александр Черемикин Я пускал такой скрипт, и все работает  $(function () {

    $("#box").on("click", function () {
        alert("Hi!");
    });
});

Comment: Проверьте, может у вас с id что-то не так или в хроме установлены какие-то глючные плагины.

Comment: Запускал хром в режиме ингонито, выключал все плагины...пробовал на другом компе. Ни работает. Попробую с ID  покопаться. Спасибо!

Comment: У меня #client_1 это оптион селекта. Может с этим связано? Есть у кого идеи? Это 100% с этим связано. Так как я задал в js клин на простой блочный элемент то все сработало. Пошел разбираться. Все спасибо!

Comment: Т.е. приведённый вами же сниппет у вас работает? В чём тогда смысл этого вопроса?

Comment: В хроме не работает. Так как я пытаюсь задать событие клик на <option> Надо попробовать событие change на select.

Comment: У вас пример не соответствует тому, что вы говорите в комментариях. Почему вы не сделали `select` в вопросе и не показали нормальный пример? Но при этом вы добавили полностью рабочий пример сюда, и говорите, что он не работает. Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Исправил. Снипет не я написал. Сейчас исправил. В FF работает нормально с хрома не работает.

Comment: Не работает, потому что неверное событие используете для этого тега. Вот аналогичный вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540541/trying-to-get-a-jquery-event-to-fire-onclick-on-a-select-option-form

Comment: @АлександрЧеремикин, извините, действительно, сниппет добавили не вы.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf зачем добавили в код то, что явно противоречит намерениям автора? ц-ц-ц)

Comment: У меня другой вопрос возникает: а обязан ли вообще работать onclick на option?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев когда я добавлял сниппет, автор ничего не говорил про select.

Comment: @andreymal думаю нет, потому что это элемент браузера, а не html, так же как и alert, например. Хотя точно не знаю)

Comment: Вот ещё похожий вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome

Comment: Прошу прощение за изначально не правильно поставленный вопрос. Я не думал что option "особенный").

Comment: Вообще стандарт HTML5 вроде намекает, что он не должен быть особенным, так что это наверно стоит считать багом хрома, а пока можем предложить костыль с onchange

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение. Всем спасибо за направление. Очень рад что здесь такие отзывчивые люди.  Спасибо за терпение и понимание!

```js
$("#agent_1").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find(':selected').val() === '1') {
    alert('test');
  } else {
    alert('test2');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="agents" id="agent_1">
  <option value="1">Test</option>
  <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: можно брать значение не как вы это делаете (это ужасно), а сразу с ивента, который идет на входе в обработчике (`on('change', function(event)`). `event.target.value` будет значение выбранной опции

Comment: Спасибо большое. На будущее учту.